# ListFragment inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a Viewpager, that contain fragments, and a listfragment, the listfragment gets data from a asynctask, and then uses the setListAdapter to set the data, the only problem is, the data is not showing. Does anyone have a suggestion to address this problem?

```
public class AndroidViewPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager mViewPager;
TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
    setContentView(mViewPager);

    final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab1"),
            FragmentB.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab2"),
            FragmentA.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab3"),
            FragmentC.class, null);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 1));

    }

    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.menuitem2:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "menu klikket!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("tab", getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}

public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(),
                info.args);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

}
```

And a Class FragmentA

```
public class FragmentA extends ListFragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenta,
            container, false);

    return myFragmentView;

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v("ListFragment", "onActivityCreated().");
    Log.v("ListsavedInstanceState", savedInstanceState == null ? "true"
            : "false");

    // Generate list View from ArrayList
    new GetList().execute();

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}

class GetList extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(
            getActivity());

                    //Data is retrieved from a server, and added to the ListAdapter

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), contactList,
                R.layout.fragmenta, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_UID,
                        TAG_START }, new int[] { R.id.email_label,
                        R.id.mobile_label, R.id.mobile_label });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        Log.e("LIST", "setListAdapter is done");
    }
}
```

My code runs fine, but the list is not showing. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: is this getting logged? `Log.v("ListFragment", "onActivityCreated().");` and what about `Log.e("LIST", "setListAdapter is done");`

Comment: I just added that to see if the code was executing.

Comment: So it is not getting logged?  Or is it?  -- This will help us know if the problem is in the fragment or the adapter.

Comment: It is getting logged, so the code runs, so from that i think the problem is in the fragment.

Comment: It works great when I use it in a listActivity..

Comment: The solution to the problem was to use a simple arrayadapter!